# DAVDroid CalDAV Calender does not show as phone calender account

Tags: calendar, caldav

I have a Xiaomi Redmi 4X Device with stock Android (no custom OS installation or modifications). I run a Radicale CalDAV server at home and have installed the DAVDroid app (via F-Droid). Inside DAVDroid app, I have set up the connection to my CalDAV server and DAVDroid shows up the calendar, so the connection to the server is fine.

Problems occur when I want to use the calendar with the Calendar app on the phone. In the calendar app, I want (i.e. I have) to choose the CalDAV calendar as a "calendar account", but the DAVDroid account is not showing up in the list of available calendar accounts although it definitely exists.

(I did some other tests using the aCalDAV app from the Google Play Store and the aCalDAV account shows up and is working).

Is there maybe a problem that DAVDroid has because it does not have all the needed permissions? I have no idea how to resolve the issue, so any hints are welcome.

Comment: I'm not familiar with this app, but it sounds like it just doesn't support being used with the system calendar storage. If you don't get an answer here you should ask the developer of the app.

Comment: That seems like an issue with the "default calendar app", as it works with others (OP described such). So the easiest solution is using [a 3rd party calendar app](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/office_calendar_general), e.g. [ETar](https://f-droid.org/packages/ws.xsoh.etar/). I'm a long-term user of DAVDroid (on multiple devices, though no Xiaomi) and never had that issue (I'm using [Business Calendar Pro](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=mikado.bizcalpro) in case you want to know).

Answer (score 1):

I solved the issue. It was an issue with a permission problem, that prevented DAVDroid to do synchronisation. I assume that I granted the permissions "too late" (after DAVDroid already tried a sync before the correct permissions and failed).

A restart of the phone and manual re-triggering of the synchronisation process solved the problem.